# Is it possible to manage number format in guide_colorsteps?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to ask if it is possible to fix labels generated by the guide_colorsteps function in the same format with breaks used in the `geom_contour_filled` function used for plotting?

Here is my example:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(y=eruptions, x=waiting, z=100*density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf, -2.0, -1.5, -1.0, -0.05, -0.005, 0, 0.005, 0.05, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0, 9.0, 11.0, Inf)) + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10,hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = heat.colors(18),drop=FALSE) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorsteps(barheight = unit(par("pin")[2], "in")))
```

which gives an output like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqrtA.png)

As you can see in the legend, there are added zeros to the numbers used in breaks (0 -> 0.000, 1.0 -> 1.000 etc.). I would like to have the numbers in the legend in the same format as I wrote them in the breaks.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hello Quinten, I have edited my contribution so that the code in it contains now reproducible data for you. Thank you a lot for any suggestions on how to solve my problem.